# How to remove a stuck flexible installer bit?

Tags: drill

While attempting to add an Ethernet run to a exterior wall (no crawlspace access beneath the wall - oops) I have managed to get my [flexible installer bit](http://www.idealindustries.com/products/tools_totes/saws_drill_bits/flexible_drill_bits.jsp) (example in link) completely stuck. I have a 6A corded drill and it can't budge it; I've also tried vice grips and yanking on it as hard as I can.

I'd really rather not just cut the rod off the bit - it was pretty expensive. Does anyone know of any tricks on how to remove a bit that has become stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations on using a very good tool for that project, but condolences on getting it stuck! Definitely too expensive to abandon. The only way I know to recover a stuck bit like that is to back it off. You may need to borrow a stronger drill such as a Milwaukee hole hog or some other gear driven heavy duty drill. In the future, always try to use a very strong drill as a flex bit tends to bind easily as it worms it way through thick stacks of framing. Also try clearing the debris from the bit trail by backing off the bit a little when engaging a thick bore and letting debris clear before pushing forward. This will help minimize binding.

Comment: Shirlock - When I thought to ask this question, it was you specifically I was hoping to hear some kind of sage wizardry from ... shucks! I'll look into renting a heavy duty drill. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, sorry I got no magic bullet for ya. I'll try harder next time.